# How to obtain the infimum of this inequalities?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be the family of functions $f(z)=z+a_2z^2+\cdots$ that are analytic in unit disk $D:\{z:|z|<1\}$ and $S$ is the subfamily of functions that are univalent in $D$. $R(a)$ is the subfamily of $A$ consisting of functions $f$ for which $\operatorname{Re}(f'(z)+zf''(z))>a$, $a<1$.

If $f\in R(a)$, then $\operatorname{Re}f'(z)>(1-a)(2\log2-1)+a$. How to obtain the infimum of the inequalities so that we can show $R(a) \subset S$ ?

Comment: What is $\,a\,$, what is $\,R(a)\,$ ...? Apparently $\,f\,$ is a function...or not?

Comment: @DonAntonio: i already gave details info.. tqsm

Comment: What book (paper?) is this from? The inequality you give is presented without proof or context, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Not sure if I read this 100% correct. You are looking for $\inf\{a\mid R(a)\subseteq S\}$?